# Typescript - Can't increment number

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to increment a property in a class, and for some reason the property is acting like it isn't a number.
the problem is specifically in this code:

```
addKill() {
        this.kills++
        this.updateDbPlayer(this.playFabId, ''+this.elo, ''+this.kills, ''+this.deaths).then(e => console.log('player atualizado ' + this.playFabId))
        return this.kills
    }
```

i'm creating the property as simple as possible: kills:number = 0

the entire class

class Player:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';
interface GetItemOutputPlayer extends DynamoDB.GetItemOutput {
    playfabId: string,
    elo: number,
    kills: number,
    deaths: number
}
export class Player {
    dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ 'region': 'sa-east-1' })
    docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    playFabId: string;
    kills: number = 0;
    deaths: number = 0;
    elo: number = 1500;
    constructor(playFabId: string) {
        this.playFabId = playFabId;
    }
    init(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let params = {
                Key: {
                    "playfabId": {
                        S: this.playFabId
                    }
                },
                TableName: "libradRanked"
            }
            this.dynamodb.getItem(params, (err, resp) => {
                if (err) throw err
                if (!resp.Item) {
                    this.updateDbPlayer(this.playFabId, ''+this.elo, ''+this.kills, ''+this.deaths).then(e => console.log('player criado ' + this.playFabId))
                } else {
                    let item = resp.Item
                    this.elo = <number>item.elo
                    this.kills = <number>item.kills
                    this.deaths = <number>item.deaths
                }

                resolve(true)
            })
        })
    }

    addKill() {
        this.kills++
        this.updateDbPlayer(this.playFabId, ''+this.elo, ''+this.kills, ''+this.deaths).then(e => console.log('player atualizado ' + this.playFabId))
        return this.kills
    }
    addDeath() {
        this.deaths++
        this.updateDbPlayer(this.playFabId, ''+this.elo, ''+this.kills, ''+this.deaths).then(e => console.log('player atualizado ' + this.playFabId))
        return this.deaths
    }
    changeElo(newElo: number) {
    }
    private updateDbPlayer(playfab: string, elo: string, kills: string, deaths: string) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {

            let params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.PutItemInput = {
                TableName: 'libradRanked',
                Item: {
                    "playfabId": {
                        S: playfab
                    },
                    "elo": {
                        N: elo
                    },
                    "kills": {
                        N: kills
                    },
                    "deaths": {
                        N: deaths
                    }
                }
            };
            this.dynamodb.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err
                resolve(data)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "the property is acting like it isn't a number". Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: 1. What is `item.kills`? You use a type assertion `<number>` for it *but that won't actually change the type*. You have to make sure it's correct. 2. How are you calling `addKill()`?

Comment: @SimonK this.kills++ is resulting in this.kills=NaN

Comment: @VLAZ item.kills it's a number, even on debbug it shows it as a number but when i call an increment like this.kills++ it becomes a NaN.
about how i'm calling addkill(), in another file i have an array of players where i find the player that makes the kill and call the function :
        let killer = players.find(e => e.playFabId == arr[0])!; killer.addKill()

Comment: Aha! There's your problem. Will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not mapping the response from DynamoDB correctly.
Best explanation is to show you how to map it properly:

```
let item = resp.Item;
this.elo = +item.elo.N;
this.kills = +item.kills.N;
this.deaths = +item.deaths.N;
```

`item.kills` in your current code is an object with the property `N` which is of data type `string`. To map correctly, you need to access it and then convert it to a number (as shown above).